# What's the correct way to post open source code on SO which isn't CC-Wiki?

Tags: discussion, legal, copyright, licensing

I tried to [answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10501534/34088) related to the open source [Apache Portable Runtime Project](https://apr.apache.org/).

I found the answer to the question in the sources (in this case, the test cases) of the project. The project is under a [APL 2.0](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0).

Since the OP uses the project, the license is probably OK for them but the license isn't compatible with CC-Wiki (SO's license).

[An answer to this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51357/131188) says:

> The cc license cannot, and does not, override the terms of an existing license.

So the code fragment is still under APL even though I posted it here. So I added the link to the license plus the license header.

Questions:

1. Is it generally OK/correct/legal to post code from OSS projects on SO?
2. Are there OSS licenses which specifically forbid sharing via SO?
3. ... or which can cause other unintentional trouble (like posting GPL code here would make SO GPL'd or something)?
4. Is my way of posting correct / too much (maybe the license is enough and I could omit the license header) / not enough?

Comment: This is why I hate lawyers

Comment: Seems silly they would put a license on their test code...

Comment: The license is for all the code in the project. And why would they select a different license for tests?

Comment: @AaronDigulla: because there is no reason to license tests or samples.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Are you sure? Did you ask a lawyer? ;-)

Comment: @AaronDigulla: I work for a company which would consider *variable names* to be proprietary information.

Comment: You sure you are allowed around here? Or is a security detail already on its way to "handle" you ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're going to post the *whole source* which is under a given license, then yes you should ensure that the license is well known to any viewer of the answer. This is not incompatible with the CC-Wiki license.

If you're going to post a snippet or small section--keep in mind I am not a lawyer--then I would believe you are covered under fair use. Furthermore, you should attribute the source the snippet so as to not violate the spirit of either of the licenses.

However, you probably should not be posting the *entire* source in an answer (unless it is trivial). Enough of a sample to get the questioner going in the right direction is fine and preferred over copy-pasting an entire file.